# How to get 'rel' value from datalist->option element when selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-datalist

I have simple datalist:

```
<datalist id="AddressEcontList">
    <option rel="9605" value="Балчик Левски"></option>
    <option rel="9005" value="Варна Левски"></option>
    <option rel="3012" value="Враца Левски"></option>
    <option rel="4804" value="Девин Васил Левски"></option>
    <option rel="5901" value="Левски"></option>
    <option rel="8900" value="Нова Загора В.Левски"></option>
    <option rel="5806" value="Плевен Васил Левски"></option>
    <option rel="4032" value="Пловдив Васил Левски"></option>
    <option rel="8806" value="Сливен Васил Левски"></option>
    <option rel="1038" value="София Левски"></option>
</datalist>
```

This is my input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" list="AddressEcontList" placeholder="demo123" id="AddressEcontOffice">
```

and this is my current code for trying to find the option element and extract the rel value from it, but it is not working

```
$('#AddressEcontOffice').on('change', function (e) {
  let value = $(this).val();
  let rel = $('#AddressEcontList[value="' + value + '"]').attr('rel');
});
```

I am getting `undefined` and when i try with only `$('#AddressEcontList[value="' + value + '"]')` i am getting this

> n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "#AddressEcontList[value="Левски"]"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to the selector. The `value` attribute is on the child `option` elements, not the `#AddresEcontList` itself, so you need to separate them with a space. Try this:

```js
$('#AddressEcontOffice').on('change', function(e) {
  let value = $(this).val();
  let rel = $('#AddressEcontList option[value="' + value + '"]').attr('rel');
  console.log(value);
  console.log(rel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" list="AddressEcontList" placeholder="demo123" id="AddressEcontOffice">
<datalist id="AddressEcontList">
    <option rel="9605" value="Балчик Левски"></option>
    <option rel="9005" value="Варна Левски"></option>
    <option rel="3012" value="Враца Левски"></option>
    <option rel="4804" value="Девин Васил Левски"></option>
    <option rel="5901" value="Левски"></option>
    <option rel="8900" value="Нова Загора В.Левски"></option>
    <option rel="5806" value="Плевен Васил Левски"></option>
    <option rel="4032" value="Пловдив Васил Левски"></option>
    <option rel="8806" value="Сливен Васил Левски"></option>
    <option rel="1038" value="София Левски"></option>
</datalist>
```